# Regex replacing character immediately after matches

Tags: javascript, regex

## The Problem

I'm using Regex to replace all occurrences of the number 1 in a given html() string. However, I don't want it to replace the 1 in 12, for example. I'm doing this to make certain parts of cloning a form easier.

So far, it works. However, it also replaces the character immediately after the match. For example, I'm trying to replace the 1 in `name[1]` to make it `name[2]` - however, it ends up as `name[2`. See the snippet below;

***note*** - odd issue with the snippet. After duplicating the element, the entire thing disappears. Same thing happens on JSfiddle but not locally.

```js
$("form").on("click", ".add-race", function(){
    var row = $(".add-race-row").first(); // use this to clone the section
    var newRow = row.clone();
    newRow.html(newRow.html().replace(/1[^12]/g,"2"));

    console.log("clicked!");

    $(".add-race-row").last().after(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="row add-race-row">
        <div class="col-12">
             <input name="races[1][name]" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12"> 
             <button class="add-race">Add Race</button>
        </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead instead : `1(?=[^12])`

With your initial RegEx, you were replacing the whole match : `1` and whatever was after.

Here, I only check that what's after the `1` isn't a `1` or a `2`. I'm not matching it.

```js
$(".add-race").on("click", function() {
  var row = $(".add-race-row").first(); // use this to clone the section
  var newRow = row.clone();
  newRow.html(newRow.html().replace(/1(?=[^12])/g, "2"));

  console.log("clicked!");

  $(".add-race-row").last().after(newRow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row add-race-row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <input name="races[1][name]" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="add-race">Add Race</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to match `1` not followed with `1` or `2` use

```
.replace(/1(?![12])/g,"2")
           ^^^^^^^^
```

Here,

- `1` - matches `1`
- `(?![12])` - a *negative lookahead* asserts the location that is not immediately followed with `1` or `2`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ew7ebh/1).